# SpriteKit sample game bug: textures not loading?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

[image: Game "up and running"]

Today I tried just running the plain, unmodified "Adventure" spritekit sample [(downloaded from Apple)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/Adventure.zip) on the simulator or on the iphone, and came across a very strange behavior:

The Textures are all replaced with a big, red "X"

Threre is no runtime error at all, but when I break at the point, where the textures should be loaded, the atlas seems to be empty (after `[... atlasNamed:@"Tiles"]` ). The description printed from it is "0 textures". Furthermore, I checked the "copy bundle resources" phase, and the Tiles.atlas is included. There is also nothing suspicious about the atlases, they are added to the targets and the pictures are inside.

As I said, I just downloaded the .zip, unpacked it, opened it and tried to run it on my phone.
I have even done it twice, and cleaned up all temporary data and so on...

Can you help me, or did anybody experience the same strange problem?
Thank you in advance!

-------APPENDIX----------
Some more strange facts:

The storyboard, also not modified, refuses to show the "Archer" and "Warrior" button images, and the buttons themselves They are just invisible frames. When I make another button with the very same settings, it is visible and the image is there.

[image: Buttons invisible]

Meanwhile, I have restarted my computer completely, checked folder permissions in diskUitility, restarted Xcode a number of times, deleted the derived data, tried to remove the Tiles.atlas folder and added it again, built without the Tiles.atlas folder, rechecked the project settings (texture atlasses are enabled) etc... I´m desperate, as you can see.

Comment: thats interesting because I just downloaded it from the link I put into your post and it totally works.

Comment: Yea, truly strange... I don't see any reason why it should not work, there is not even a warning when I compile the game. The code looks normal and the project settings, too. Next step I will do is uninstall xCode completely and reinstall it...

Comment: Do you also get the 0 Textures description, when breaking after any atlas loading and clicking the info button in the inspector? In this case, I had to look elsewhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue:

Try putting the game into a folder with any of the following vowels: ä ö ü

That is german "Umlaute". That is no problem for any of the other APIs from Apple, but Java has a problem with it (BlueJ does not see folders with those letters, for example) and appearently SpriteKit, too.

In the end, the atlas files were not copied to the bundle at all, due to the path with an "Umlaut" in it. That is an XCode or Compiler bug. Where to file a report about that? Or can somebody do that for me?

Comment: I filed the bug report. Number 16152428

Comment: Hey thanks for filing the radar. The community loves you for it. Also sorry i didn't see your post until now.

Comment: Hey, no reason for apologies! Nobody is there 24/7 :) I'm just relieved that it is a reproducible bug and I'm not crazy...